# transfer iOS app in Test Flight but never released to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-transfer

Apple has a new policy requiring medical apps like mine to be submitted by healthcare organizations, not individual physician programmers like me.  I have an app I worked on for a couple months, loaded it to AppStoreConnect, sent it out on Test Flight, good feedback, ready to release.  But cannot release as individual physician.  So went to my employer healthcare organization.  They'd be happy to publish my app.  I now have credentials within their developers account.  When I try to upload my same app (rebuilt with new certificates and identifiers for organization), I can't get it to upload because Apple flags my upload as copying someone else's material -- my own material!  It sees that "Cardiovascular Risk" app submitted under my healthcare organization is just like my "cardiovascular Risk" app submitted also by me under my personal developers account!  If the app were already approved at least once, I could transfer it.  But since never approved for the App Store, I cannot use the Transfer App process that Apple offers.  Any ideas?

Best,
-- Josh

Comment: Just pick a new bundle id and set it up as a new app in your employer's account.   There is no need to transfer if it was never released

Comment: You can remove your app from your account and push everything to store using new account. This will allow you to submit it.

Comment: Please trim back story to focus on the actual question for getting question faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, msusare, that was the only solution.  New bundle and new submission didn't work because AppStoreConnect saw my old submission and flagged it.  I did not realize one could remove the entire app.  Removal of the entire app from my old personal account and then posting the same app to new new account with my employer (with new bundle ID) worked.  Thanks!